# Replaying RPC calls for testing purposes

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, rpc

We are using a 3rd party library (Google Spanner) that uses gRPC in a node application. One of pain points we have is ability to easily mock responses from this library for testing purposes.

If anyone had similar issues, were you able to solve it? I was thinking of a tool that could record/replay rpc calls (there are many great libraries for recording/replaying HTTP calls) but couldn't find anything similar for RPC. I came up across Google's rpcreplay (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/tree/master/rpcreplay) but to my understanding it's intended to be used in Go applications.

Answer (score 1):

At [Traffic Parrot](https://trafficparrot.com) we have been working on a solution to your problem in our [service virtualization tool](https://trafficparrot.com/trial.html) which includes a user interface that can be used to define the mock behaviour.

We have recently added a [tutorial](https://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/mocking-and-simulating-grpc.html) on how to mock gRPC responses over the wire given a proto file.

You can also find information on how to record and replay over the wire in the [documentation](https://trafficparrot.com/documentation/?redirectToLatest=true&path=/grpc.html).

[image: Traffic Parrot gRPC user interface]
[image: Recording gRPC messages]
[image: Replaying gRPC messages]